# Change column width in Google Sheet embed and allow users to edit but not commit changes to original document

Tags: html

So I've embedded a Google Sheet into my website as a pricing table and would like to allow clients to edit certain cells and add mathematical operations in them. Also once I embedded the page, all the columns are the same width and make some of the headers' titles squished. Can someone help me out?

Comment: could you please add your code whatever you have done so far

Comment: Here's my iframe:
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSQ3wZY7rvk0qNRJ24_nHJ2hIWRwkkIJT0KVM_EaevH2rfVqGfexdMuTPgykKSY6xHPI_HL8097ANDY/pubhtml?gid=0&amp;single=true&amp;widget=true&amp;headers=false"></iframe>